# How to place http.Serve in its own goroutine if it blocks?

Tags: go, concurrency

[`http.Serve`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve) either returns an error as soon as it is called or blocks if successfully executing.

How can I make it so that if it blocks it does so in its own goroutine? I currently have the following code:

```
func serveOrErr(l net.Listener, handler http.Handler) error {
    starting := make(chan struct{})
    serveErr := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        starting <- struct{}{}
        if err := http.Serve(l, handler); err != nil {
            serveErr <- err 
        }   
    }()
    <-starting

    select {
    case err := <-serveErr:
        return err
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

This seemed like a good start and works on my test machine but I believe that there are no guarantees that `serveErr <- err` would be called before `case err := <-serveErr` therefore leading to inconsistent results due to a data race if `http.Serve` were to produce an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http.Serve either returns an error as soon as it is called or blocks if successfully executing

This assumption is not correct. And I believe it rarely occurs. [`http.Serve`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=56308:56354#L1873) calls `net.Listener.Accept` in the loop – an error can occur any time (socket closed, too many open file descriptors etc.). It's `http.ListenAndServe`, usually being used for running http servers, which often fails early while binding listening socket (no permissions, address already in use).

In my opinion what you're trying to do is wrong, unless really your `net.Listener.Accept` is failing on the first call for some reason. Is it? If you want to be 100% sure your server is working, you could try to connect to it (and maybe actually transmit something), but once you successfully bound the socket I don't see it really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. What I am doing is wrong. I thought `net.Listener.Accept` was the function that returned the binding errors on first use but in fact `net.Listen` is the culprit which makes things a lot easier. For the time being I'll just panic if `http.Serve` via `net.Listener.Accept` produces an error. If I find this error path is frequent then I can use a channel to pipe the error to and let callers of the function `serveOnErr` listen on the channel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a timeout on your select statement, e.g.

```
timeout := time.After(5 * time.Millisecond) // TODO: ajust the value
select {
case err := <-serveErr:
    return err
case _ := <- timeout:
    return nil
}
```

This way your select will block until `serveErr` has a value or the specified `timeout` has elapsed. Note that the execution of your function will therefore block the calling goroutine for up to the duration of the specified timeout.

Rob Pike's excellent talk on [go concurrency patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) might be helpful.